# Object of type InputMediaDocument is not JSON serializable, i tried to send file over telegram bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

query.edit_message_text(InputMediaDocument("https://t.me/aastuchem/125"))

TypeError: Object of type InputMediaDocument is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a document to a text message that didn't have a document in it before. To edit the document in a message that does have a document in it, you'll have to use [`query.edit_message_media`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.callbackquery.html#telegram.CallbackQuery.edit_message_media) and note that providing a link to a telegram message doesn't work. See also this [wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#working-with-files-and-media).